# How do you prove the two integrals are unequal?

Tags: integration

I think the following two integrations are different by intuition and by enumeration:

$$\left[\int_a^b f(x)dx\right]^{-1} \text{and} \int_a^b \left[f(x)\right]^{-1}dx$$

However, I want a mathematically rigorous proof. Thank you in advance!

Comment: They are certainly different expressions with different definitions.  As numeric values they *might* be equal, but this would be a special case.  If you are simply trying to show the numeric values are *not identical* for all (integrable? invertible?) functions $f(x)$, it would suffice to give a counterexample.  That should be pretty easy, as almost any guess will be likely to give two different values.  But perhaps you mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample will be fine. Consider the constant function $f\equiv 1$:
$$
\left(\int_a^b f(x)dx\right)^{-1} = \left(\int_a^b dx\right)^{-1} = \left(b-a\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{b-a}
$$
while
$$
\int_a^b \left(f(x)\right)^{-1}dx = \int_a^b dx = {b-a}
$$
Now, choose for instance $a=0$, $b=2$ to see these are not equal.

Comment: Haha, we thought exactly the same :-)

Comment: You do beat me by 6 seconds. Darn!

Comment: Yours is definitely more informative. Have a +1.

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample fully suffices as a proof for inequalities. Take $a = 0$, $b = 2$, $f(x) = 1$ (a constant).